# Slowly supplying power to a very high load

Tags: mosfet, switches, high-voltage, high-current

Is it possible to supply power to a very high load within a huge time range?

This question particularly regards MOSFETs.
I know that a MOSFET must switch fast so that a little power would develop upon it's Drain-Source junction.

But what if I want a MOSFET to supply 5V, 10A to a load, while it's OFF to ON transition takes 10 seconds? (just an example, not a real scenario)
That case, what would I need to do in order to accomplish this?
Is it possible/realistic to accomplish with MOSFET or should I use other devices/components?

I've seen an "electronic switch" that it's *OFF to ON time adjustment* feature has been disabled, because that the MOSFET can't sustain high power while the slow transition occurs.

---

**Edit #1 (27 Aug 2013, 20:00 UTC):**
Would you say that [HUF76629D3ST_F085](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/HU/HUF76629D_F085.pdf) is good for the job?

Comment: Is the load pure resistance (0.5R)?

Comment: What is the nature of the load? Some loads would not mind a PWM drive, where you switch the MOSFET fast but ramp the duty cycle up over 10 seconds. Others might tolerate a L-C or capacitively smoothed PWM drive.

Comment: @JImDearden: Yes, the load is a pure resistance.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: There isn't a specific type of load in my mind. I'm just searching for a generic solution. Although, I think that a proper solution would suit for a generic *Electronic Switch* - that would have the least interference with the circuit to which it supplies power, and with a neat steady ramp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the answer is simply to put a suitable heatsink on the MOSFET.

**Assuming there is a 1V difference between the input and (final) output voltage** of the regulator. This means that the input to the MOSFET is 6V.

Over a period of 10 seconds the output voltage increases from 0 to 5V across a 0.5R resistance load.

This means the output current will rise in a linear fashion from 0A to 10A as the output voltage increases from 0V to 5V.

The voltage **ACROSS** the MOSFET will decrease in a linear fashion from 6V to 1V.

With a 1 volt drop across the regulator this means the MOSFET must handle 10W after the 10 second period.

During the 10 second power up period the power dissipated by the MOSFET rises from 0W (at t=0 , I= 0, Vds = 6V) to a maximum at around 6 seconds of 18W and then falls to the final value of 10W.

**The circuit is not power efficient** (not asked for in the OQ) but a good heatsink should be able to cope with this level of power dissipation without cooking the MOSFET.

[image]

Comment: It depende on the MOSFET physical size but maybe the heatsink is not necessary. Maybe its thermal capacity is big enough to keep the junction temperature low.

Comment: @JIm Dearden: Thanks for the detailed answer! Plz see my 1st edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a restive load, and DC power you can do what is called [PWM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation), if you are supplying AC you can build a [dimmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimmer).

Comment: The supplied voltage is DC. But I learned from your answer! +1 for now.